Definition for "almost simple" linear algebraic groups
Proposition 2.18 from "Elementary abelian $p$-subgroups of algebraic groups" by R. Griess. used the term "simply connected almost simple linear algebraic group $G$" without defining it.
In the abstract, "nearly simple linear algebraic group" is defined as: the connected component of the identity $G^{\circ}$ is perfect, $C_G(G^{\circ}) = Z(G^{\circ})$ and $G^{\circ}/Z(G^{\circ})$ is simple.
I don't suppose they are the same... What is the definition for "almost simple" here?

The connected component of the identity of a nearly simple linear algebraic group is almost simple.

So you mean like $G$ is almost simple if G is connected, perfect and $G/Z(G)$ is simple? Thanks for your input!

The standard definition of "almost simple" is that a group $G$ is almost simple if $S \le G \le {\rm Aut}(S)$ for some nonabelian simple group $S$. I would guess that the authors are using the standard meaning.

Sorry this may sound stupid. But isn't your definition for finite groups?...

You got it. Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803510/definitions-for-almost-simple-algebraic-group

It's not my definition! But it appears that the one I gave is not the definition of an almost simple algebraic group that is being used here, so ignore my comment.
